# Node.js puppeteer - Use values from array in a loop to cycle through pages

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. ... now I want to visit different pages based on inregular values from an array:

My array looks like this:

```
rows = [ RowDataPacket {
            id: 1,
            value: 'L3',
            name: 'Steve' },
        RowDataPacket {
            id: 2,
            value: 'GU',
            name: 'Peter' },        
        RowDataPacket {
            id: 3,
            value: 'M5',
            name: 'John' }]
```

So the pages I want to visit are:

```
await page.goto('url/search?action=getname&name=L3', {waitUntil: 'load'});  
await page.goto('url/search?action=getname&name=GU', {waitUntil: 'load'});  
await page.goto('url/search?action=getname&name=M5', {waitUntil: 'load'});
```

The array is actually 200 values long ... so I thought of doing a loop like this:

```
await page.goto('url', {waitUntil: 'load'});

rows = [ RowDataPacket {
            id: 1,
            value: 'L3',
            name: 'Steve' },
        RowDataPacket {
            id: 2,
            value: 'GU',
            name: 'Peter' },        
        RowDataPacket {
            id: 3,
            value: 'M5',
            name: 'John' }]

console.log(rows.length); // 3

for (let i=1; i < rows.length; i++){

    await page.goto('url/search?action=getname&name='+value, {waitUntil: 'load'});  

}
```

But how can I access the values ('value') from the array and use it in the loop accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `browser.newPage();` inside the loop, like this:

```
const page = []

    for (let i=1; i < rows.length; i++){

        page[i] = await browser.newPage();
        await  page[i].goto('url/search?action='+rows[i].name+'&name='+rows[i].value, {waitUntil: 'load'});

    }
```

Then, in the same or other for:

```
const newPage = await page[i].evaluate(() => {
```

Comment: @PhilippM sure doing `rows[i].value`

Comment: I'm getting a error though: page[i] = await browser.newPage(); .... SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what’s in the `rows` array, as `[ RowDataPacket {` is not valid JavaScript, but assuming that’s a stand-in for the actual data, and each row has a `value` property, you can use simpler syntax:

```
for (const row of rows) {
  await page.goto(`url/search?action=getname&name=${row.value}`);
}
```

If you want to create a new page each time, per Emeeus’s answer, you can wrap it in `try`/`finally`:

```
for (const row of rows) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    await page.goto(`url/search?action=getname&name=${row.value}`);
  } finally {
    await page.close();
  }
}
```

Notes:

- [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is the modern variant of a `for` loop.
- The code starting with backticks is [a template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which lets you avoid concatenation.
- [`waitUntil` defaults to `load`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), so you can leave it out.